# Derivative of nabla operation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-derivative, laplace-transform, laplacian

$$ x = x' \cos \theta - y'\sin \theta   \\
y = x' \sin \theta + y'\cos \theta
 $$

$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x'} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \cos \theta + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \sin \theta $$

are given. I don't understand how the partial derivative with respect to $x'$ is obtained. Can you explain?

$$ \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x'^2} = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}\cos^2\theta+ \frac{\partial }{\partial x}(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y})\sin\theta\cos\theta + \frac{\partial }{\partial y}(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x})\cos\theta\sin\theta +  \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}\sin^2\theta $$

Answer (score 2):

You have
$$ \begin{cases}
x = x'\cos\theta - y'\sin\theta\\
y = x'\sin\theta + y'\sin\theta
\end{cases} \quad\Rightarrow\quad
\begin{cases}
\frac{\partial x}{\partial x'} = \cos\theta\\
\frac{\partial y}{\partial x'} = \sin\theta\\
\end{cases} $$
so that you can apply the chain rule to get
$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x'} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial x'} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial x'}
= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \cos\theta + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\sin\theta. $$
Can you do the second partial derivative on your own now?